# Can I specify in gradle that I only want to use a certain plugin for tests?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I have a project and for testing purposes only I want to standup a quick websocket server. Spring Boot seems like the simplest way to do that, but I don't want to include the plugin in my implementation, only for tests. I can't seem to find documentation on something like this, but in general I've found the answer to the question "can gradle do this" is usually yes.

So how would I go about specifying to only use the 'org.springframework.boot' plugin for test builds?

I've tried placing the plugins {} block inside a test {} block but that doesn't work.

Comment: "but I don't want to include the plugin in my implementation". This sentence makes no sense at all. How would a Gradle plugin be included in your implementation?

Comment: @LukasKörfer probably just bad wording, I'm not gradle expert. I just want to make sure that the plugin isn't causing anything to be packaged up with my non-test code. So, can I infer from your comment that I don't need to worry about the spring boot plugin doing that, and can just proceed with adding it normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you may just apply the `org.springframework.boot` plugin in the regular way and it won't effect your build artifacts.

However, it is possible to apply plugins dynamically, if you are afraid that they might have undesired side-effects on build artifacts. The old plugin mechanism actually worked this way by default and separated the resolution of plugins from their application to the `Project` instance:

```
// This part resolves the plugin
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.3.2.RELEASE'
  }
}

// This part applies the plugin
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
```

This way it was possible to apply a plugin based on a condition:

```
if (testMode) {
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
}
```

Using the new `plugins` block to apply plugins, this is not possible directly, as the `plugins` block is a special block that does not allow custom code:

```
// This is not allowed!
plugins {
    if (testMode) {
        id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.2.RELEASE'
    }
}
```

The solution is to tell the `plugins` block to resolve a plugin [without applying it](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/plugin/use/PluginDependencySpec.html#apply-boolean-) automatically. This can then be done dynamically using `apply plugin:`:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.2.RELEASE' apply false
}

if (testMode) {
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `org.springframework.boot` plugin: just use `io.spring.dependency-management` plugin. This way, you will be able to declare spring-* related dependencies in your `testImplementation` configuration, without any impact on the `implementation` configuration.

```
plugins {
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}
dependencies {

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.2.0.RELEASE"
    }
}
```

Then in your test sources, you will be able to declare SpringBoot application and other websocket-related stuff (controllers)

**EDIT** what `org.springframework.boot` is actually doing, is to change the packaging of the main `jar` artifact by declaring the `bootJar` task, see [Springboot plugin reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#reacting-to-other-plugins). In your case you don't need this, as far as I understand, if you just want to run some Spring application in test sourceset.